# Swift Timer or Notification Notification Center addObserver issue

Tags: ios, swift, timer, viewcontroller, uilocalnotification

[image]

I have a tab bar controller & it has 2 tabs **(Home & Cart)**

30 seconds after launching the app, I want to display label on 2nd VC. (Cart VC)

If user goes to 2nd tab before 30 seconds, then the label on 2nd VC should not be visible.

If the user goes to 2nd VC after 30 seconds, then the label should be visible.

How to achieve this functionality?

Comment: What problem are you facing programmatically? And, what do you mean by addObserver issue?

Comment: 10 seconds after launching the app, I want to display label on 1st VC. And 20 seconds after launching the app I want to display another label on 2nd VC

Comment: Well, just setup timers (Timer) to display your labels. You can do that in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` after you have created your controllers.